# File Upload error using phone gap and php

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to Upload a image from android Emulator, using phonegap, while transferring the file from emulator to php file in server i'm getting File Transfer error. Can any one please suggest how to upload a image file from android emulator to php script.

Please suggest me a solution.

Below is  the code i'm using

```
console.log("File Upload Started");
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey="file";
options.fileName=imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
var params = {};
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";

options.params = params;
console.log("File Transfering Started");
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageData, encodeURI("http://127.0.0.1/upload.php"), win, fail, options);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you post the relevant code you wrote for this we can help you workout the solution.

Comment: console.log("File Upload Started");
      var options = new FileUploadOptions();
      options.fileKey="file";
      options.fileName=imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
      options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

      var params = {};
      params.value1 = "test";
      params.value2 = "param";

      options.params = params;
      console.log("File Transfering Started");
      var ft = new FileTransfer();
      ft.upload(imageData, encodeURI("http://127.0.0.1/upload.php"), win, fail, options);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `http://127.0.0.1`, I think you need to use `http://10.0.2.2`. This is because when you run that code inside of the Android emulator, it tries to access the `localhost` **of the emulator,** not your development machine. The Android folks knew this would happen so they put `10.0.2.2` as a bridge to the outside dev machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer MBillau, let me try out and when i tried to upload to my development server same error was occurred. Is the code which i posted is correct?

Comment: The code does look correct, assuming that `imageData` is a string and is the path of the image you want to upload, and assuming you have defined the `win` and `fail` functions somewhere else. Take a look at the "full example" here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer  Can you post your server logs and your logcat (if it's android) logs? We should try to figure out if the server is even getting hit or not.